# Cast list object to another list object

Tags: flutter, list, casting

How can I cast `List<TenancyEntity>` to `List<Tenancy>` ?

I use below code but get exception

```
 var a = await _tenancyLocalDataSource.getTenancyList();
 var b = a!.cast<Tenancy>();
 debugPrint(b.toString());
```

Below are the both classes

**TenancyEntity**

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import '../../../domain/model/tenancy.dart';

part 'tenancy_entity.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class TenancyEntity extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  int rentalFees;

  TenancyEntity({
    required this.rentalFees,
  });

  Tenancy toTenancy() {
    return Tenancy(
      rentalFees: rentalFees
    );
  }
}
```

**Tenancy**

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class Tenancy extends Equatable {
  final int rentalFees;

  const Tenancy({required this.rentalFees});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props {
    return [rentalFees];
  }

  @override
  bool? get stringify => true;
}
```

**Error**

```
E/flutter ( 6267): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'TenancyEntity' is not a subtype of type 'Tenancy' in type cast
```

Comment: Add class for `TenancyEntity` and `Tenancy`

Comment: Please do not vandalise your questions to get around the content length filter. There is always more information you can add to a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can a method `toTenancy` in `TenancyEntry` to to convert the same to `Tenancy`, you can use `map` method to solve this.

```
List<TenancyEntity> a = await _tenancyLocalDataSource.getTenancyList();
List<Tenancy> b = a.map((entity) => entity.toTenancy()).toList();
debugPrint(b.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

To cast List to List, you can use the map function to convert each TenancyEntity to Tenancy

```
List<TenancyEntity> a = await _tenancyLocalDataSource.getTenancyList();
List<Tenancy> b = a.map((entity) => Tenancy.fromEntity(entity)).toList();
debugPrint(b.toString());
```